# How to write a transformation function to transform RDD with reference to a Graphframe object?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, graphframes

I have a Graphframe object: g and a RDD object: candidate:

```
g = GraphFrame(v,e)
candidates_rdd.collect() 
#  [Row(source=u'a', target=u'b'),
#   Row(source=u'a', target=u'c'),
#   Row(source=u'e', target=u'a')]
```

I want to compute a path from "source" to "target" in candidates_rdd and generate a result rdd with key, value pairs ((source, target), path_list) using graphframe's breadth first search, where path_list is a list of  paths from source to target.

Example outputs:

```
(('a','b'),['a-c-b','a-d-e-b']), 
(('f','c'),[]),
(('a',d'),['a-b-e-d']
```

I wrote the below function:

```
def bfs_(row):    
    arg1 = "id = '" + row.source + "'"
    arg2 = "id = '" + row.target + "'"        
    return ((row.source, row.target), g.bfs(arg1,arg2).rdd)

results = candidates_rdd.map(bfs_)
```

I got this error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o274.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

I have tried to make the graph global or broadcast it, neither works.

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR It is not possible.

Spark doesn't support nested operations like this. Outer loop has to be not-distributed:

```
>>> [g.bfs(arg1, arg2) for arg1, arg2 in candidates_rdd.collect()]
```